# PubSub & BigQuery subscription using topic schema for TIMESTAMP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a BigQuery table with the following schema:

```
requested_at    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE            
req_url         STRING          NULLABLE
```

And a PubSub topic with the following protobuf schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Request {
  string req_url = 1;
  int64 requested_at = 2;
}
```

When I try to create a PubSub subscription using the "Write to BigQuery" delivery type and the "Use topic Schema" option, I have the following error:

```
Incompatible schema type for field 'requested_at': field is INT64 in the topic schema, but TIMESTAMP in the BigQuery table schema.
```

I don't understand why because int64 seems to be the preferred format: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#data_type_conversions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [BigQuery Subscription - Schema compatibility](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#schema_compatibility) -

> When the type in the topic schema is a string and the type in the BigQuery table is TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATE, or TIME, then any value for this field in a Pub/Sub message must adhere to the format specified for the BigQuery data type.

The link from the quote leads to the [timestamp as string description](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type).

Therefore - in your protobuf schema the `requested_at` field should be of a 'string' type rather than the 'int64' type. And that string should contain a timestamp in a string [canonical format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#canonical_format_for_timestamp_literals) - `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.F]]`